# Slide asp.net content page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a web site which has a master page and content page. I have few menu items listed on the master page template. I want to bring the pages based on link click such that, the pages are loaded by a sliding animation. Also, here i only want to slide the content page.. not the whole page. Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in following ways

in your menu click you can **call [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first)** to get the page content and show the div as in animated way.

or

put **all the page content in one page** and hide the non active contents, then Show the contends according to the menu click (you can refer [jquery tab](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) )